# Processing JSON Arrays in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have a JSON document stored in myjson table, doc column.

```
{
  "totalResultsCount": 19,
  "geonames": [
    {
      "geonameId": 2593109,
      "fcode": "ADM1"
    },
    {
      "geonameId": 3336899,
      "fcode": "ADM1"
    }, ...
```

When I run the query,

```
select j.doc.geonames.geonameId from myjson j where j.doc.geonames.fcode  like '%ADM1%';
```

I get an array of IDs.

```
[2593109,3336899,3114710,2521383,3336903,2593110,3336898,3336900,2593111,3336901,2519582,2593112,3336902,3336897,3117732,6362988,2513413,3115609,2593113]
```

How do I read this array and print each ID using a FOR LOOP?

Answer (score 1):

We can use JSON_TABLE for this purpose ,

> SQL/JSON function json_table projects specific JSON data to columns of various SQL data types. You use it to map parts of a JSON document into the rows and columns of a new, virtual table, which you can also think of as an inline view.

```
WITH json AS
 (SELECT '[2593109,3336899,3114710,2521383,3336903,2593110,3336898,3336900,2593111,3336901,2519582,2593112,3336902,3336897,3117732,6362988,2513413,3115609,2593113]' doc
  FROM   dual)
SELECT geonameId
FROM   json_table((SELECT doc FROM json)
                 ,'$[*]' columns(geonameId NUMBER path '$'))
```

**Edit**
Using `JSON_TABLE` as source in for loop

```
begin
 for i in (SELECT geonameid
             FROM json_table('[2593109,3336899,3114710,2521383,3336903,2593110,3336898,3336900,2593111,3336901,2519582,2593112,3336902,3336897,3117732,6362988,2513413,3115609,2593113]'
                             ,'$[*]' columns(geonameId NUMBER path '$')))
 loop
   dbms_output.put_line('Id: '||i.geonameid);
 end loop;
end;
/
```

Again not sure if you want this.

Reference [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbeef5b09269104fa099ab99ddbac7ef)

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have already implemented this JSON_TABLE. But, I really want to know how to use it with FOR LOOP. Like
myarray json_array_t := [1,2,3];
for 0 to myarray.size() loop .... etc.

Comment: I don't understand really, if you have json_table already implemented , just use it in for loop. Why again json_array ?json_table gives you the ability to convert your JSON to column value as similar to table

Comment: With the first Select query in my question, I got an array of values. If I could assign that array to a variable with "select into var from table", I have my array object. Then I can use array operations, either to traverse with loop or any other operations. It may be a good option to use json_table, but I want to understand the array usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON_TABLE()` function within Oracle's SQL containing a CROSS JOIN in order to parse individual column values for `product` and `fcode`, and use them in SELECT-list and WHERE condition, respectively as below :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS row_id, js.product 
  FROM myjson
 CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE( 
                 doc, '$.geonames[*]' COLUMNS (
                                               product VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.geonameId',
                                               fcode   VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.fcode'
                                              )
        ) js
  WHERE js.fcode = 'ADM1'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10acc553c67e9fb169725be5d7c75548)</kbd>

**Update :** Evaluate the following depending on your comment of need for array assignment of the returning values :

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

SQL> DECLARE
  json_array_t OWA.VC_ARR;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) - 1 AS row_id, js.product 
     FROM myjson
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( 
                          doc, '$.geonames[*]' COLUMNS (
                                               product VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.geonameId',
                                               fcode   VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.fcode'
                                               )
                ) js
    WHERE js.fcode = 'ADM1' )
  LOOP    
    json_array_t(c.row_id) := c.product;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'value for json_array_t('||c.row_id||') is '||json_array_t(c.row_id) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68363c52473e2635b73fac5f3031a36d)</kbd>

**Update 2 :** You can set array values by using your original query, and then extract all members of that array using a FOR LOOP as desired lastly :

```
DECLARE
  l_str          VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_top_obj      JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_dept_arr     JSON_ARRAY_T;
  l_dept_obj     JSON_OBJECT_T;
  l_emp_arr      JSON_ARRAY_T;
  l_emp_obj      JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
  SELECT j.doc 
    INTO l_str
    FROM myjson j 
   WHERE j.doc.geonames.fcode LIKE '%ADM1%';    
  
  l_top_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T(l_str);
  l_dept_arr := l_top_obj.get_array('geonames');
  
  FOR i IN 0 .. l_dept_arr.get_size - 1 
  LOOP
    l_dept_obj := TREAT(l_dept_arr.get(i) AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('index  : '||i||' - geonameId : ' || l_dept_obj.get_number('geonameId'));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=705c324a9fc0c2696897e33a3e23e779)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have already implemented this JSON_TABLE. But, I really want to know how to use it with FOR LOOP. Like myarray json_array_t := [1,2,3]; for 0 to myarray.size() loop .... etc. I need to pass the ids to another function one at a time in a loop.

Comment: well @SureshVeeranala , you're welcome, can check the edit out.

Comment: can we do it without using the table? I just want to store the array in a variable and do the array operation on that variable.

Comment: Yes, you can @SureshVeeranala , updated the answer.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan: I really appreciate the effort from your end and even though I am not the OP I took many learning points from this answer +1. Thank you.

Comment: I agree @Sujitmohanty30. The answers are very informative.

Comment: @Barbaros: Getting the entire doc increases the I/O. Right? When we can get the array with the select, why can't we SELECT INTO l_dept_arr directly and use the FOR LOOP from there?

Comment: maybe, need to test with real data @SureshVeeranala , I presented three, you may prefer one of them :)

Comment: The array returned from the original select query is a string though it is in an array format like [1,2,3]. Is there a way to process that as an array?